# Different style output from jsFiddle and current computer

Tags: html, css

I am designing a email-template for myself, where I have a section in the page with some icons. For this i'm using SCSS.

The icons are a `div`'s with an `img` tag in it. The icons itself work, but when resizing the `img` itself, and wanting it to be vertically aligned, it does not align it. It doesn't do anything.

[image]

When copy pasting my CSS and HTML code into [a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgeggrn1/1/), it works without any problem.

Also when putting it into an snippet it works correctly:

```css
/* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */

/* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */

html,
body {
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */

* {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
/* What it does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */

div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */

table,
td {
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}
/* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */

table {
  border-spacing: 0 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
  table-layout: fixed !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
table table table {
  table-layout: auto;
}
/* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */

img {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
/* What it does: A work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */

.mobile-link--footer a,
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}
/* What it does: Prevents underlining the button text in Windows 10 */

.button-link {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
html {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-family: "Calibri Light", sans-serif;
  color: #3a3a3a;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  html {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  html {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
.email-background {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fbf7f7;
}
.email-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #7398CE;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.email-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
}
.email-footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 125px;
}
.email-footer .line {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #7398CE;
}
.email-footer .line:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: calc(10% + 5px);
  margin-left: 25px;
  bottom: -12.5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #fbf7f7;
  border: 1px solid #7398CE;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.email-footer .email-info-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 32.5px;
}
.email-footer .email-info-container .iconContainer {
  margin-left: calc(10% + 5px);
  float: left;
}
.email-footer .email-info-container .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  border: 1px dashed #3084E5;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*      -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
            -moz-border-radius: 100%;
            border-radius: 100%;*/
}
.email-footer .email-info-container .icon .iconImage {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.email-footer .email-info-container .icon .iconImage.twitter {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->
  <title>My email</title>


  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

  <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">

  <!--[if !mso]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE"/>
    <!--<![endif]-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/css/style.css">

  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="email-background">
    <div class="email-header">
      <span class="email-title"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="email-content">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus
        te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer
        recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
      </p>

      <h2>2de kop</h2>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, oen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus
        te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer
        recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
      </p>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus
        te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer
        recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
      </p>
      <h2>2de kop</h2>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, oen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus
        te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer
        recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
      </p>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus
        te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer
        recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
      </p>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, oen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus
        te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer
        recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
      </p>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus
        te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer
        recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
      </p>


    </div>
    <div class="email-footer">
      <div class="line"></div>

      <div class="email-info-container">
        <div class="iconContainer">
          <div class="icon">
            <img class="iconImage" src="assets/baspixelwit.png" alt="na">
          </div>


          <div class="icon">
            <img class="iconImage twitter" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/twitter-128.png" alt="no">
          </div>


          <div class="icon">
            <img class="iconImage" src="http://placehold.it/35x35" alt="no">
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have also uploaded it to [a GitHub page](https://basvandriel.github.io/email-template/), where exactly the same problem occurs.

The code where this occurs is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="email-footer">
    <div class="line"></div>

    <div class="email-info-container">
        <div class="iconContainer">
            <div class="icon">
                <img class="iconImage" src="assets/baspixelwit.png" alt="na">
            </div>


            <div class="icon">
                <img class="iconImage twitter"
                     src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/twitter-128.png"
                     alt="no">
            </div>


            <div class="icon">
                <img class="iconImage"
                     src="http://placehold.it/35x35"
                     alt="no">
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.email-footer {
  width: 100%;

  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 125px;

  .line {
    position: relative;

    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;

    background: $light-blue;

    &:before {
      position: absolute;

      content: '';
      left: calc(10% + 5px);

      margin-left: 25px;
      bottom: -12.5px;
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;

      background-color: $background-color;

      border: 1px solid $light-blue;

      border-top-width: 0;
      border-left-width: 0;

      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

  }

  .email-info-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 32.5px;

    .iconContainer {
      margin-left: calc(10% + 5px);
      float: left;
    }

    .icon {
      display: inline-block;

      overflow: hidden;

      width: 75px;
      height: 75px;


      line-height: 75px;


      border: 1px dashed $dark-blue;

      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;


      /*      -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
            -moz-border-radius: 100%;
            border-radius: 100%;*/

      .iconImage {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;

        vertical-align: middle;

        &.twitter {
          width: 70%;
          height: 70%;
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

I am using no other code then the code snippet and the code above.

How does this come? Is this a CSS problem or a browser problem? I have already tried clearing out my cookies and cache. I have also tried multiple browsers, all the same result.

Comment: Is this supposed to be sent as an email eventually? If it is, it won't work regardless - no way an email-client will render that properly, regardless of alignment of images.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Aside from the email-template, why doesn't it align correctly?

Comment: you may try `display: table-cell` instead of `display: inline-block`

Comment: It wasn't working in github, but now it is. Have you changed something ?

Comment: haha yes @Kangouroops i noticed that too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, tested, and for some weird reason, it doesn't work.

You can fix it by changing a couple of CSS-rules, though:

```
.email-footer .email-info-container .icon .iconImage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

And adding `position: relative;` to the `.icon`-container.